# Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method Firebase#initializeCore on channe) Windows mod not working on flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web

When I tried to run my Flutter Project in windows mod it didn't work & giving me error

iam using Those Plugins

firebase_database: ^6.1.2

cloud_firestore: ^2.2.0

flutter_swiper: ^1.1.6

auto_size_text: ^2.1.0

firebase_auth: ^1.3.0

[image]

Comment: None of the FlutterFire plugins support Windows or Linux. You might want to have a look into https://pub.dev/packages/firedart which could be used for desktop apps. 
Other option to try might be connecting Firebase with your Flutter desktop app using http method like in this tutorial: https://medium.com/flutterdevs/http-request-dcc13e885985

Comment: That's Sad But Thanks a lot